# Music App Showing Deleted Songs In Recently Played

Tags: xbox-music, nokia-lumia-630

Recently I buy a Lumia 630 & noticed after deleting a song from native music app of phone it still shows the ghost image of the song with folder in recent play section of music app. Even after reboot deleted song's folder is shown in recent play section. Is it natural ?

Comment: Was the song stored in the phone memory or SD card? was the song actually deleted, you can check with the [official Files app](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-81-gets-official-file-manager)

Comment: I downloaded the song through 'music download unlimited' app & it was stored in SD card, I deleted it both from music app & files app(for deleting blank folder of the song). But if it remains in recent plays section for all time, is it not very annoying? In my old symbian it is not happen?

Comment: I've also noticed that since the recent update to the music app that the pictures/album names in the recent listened do not match what plays if you tap them.

Answer (score 1):

The Recently Played list will show songs, albums, artists, and playlists that no longer exist. If you try to play (from Recently Played) the song that you deleted, it will not be able to play it.

EDIT: The Music app has been updated to allow you to remove items from Recently Played.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the Music app doesn't require the song to be on the device. It has a couple states for music: installed or in the cloud (shown with a streaming icon).

If you try to play the song that has been deleted do you get a 30 second preview? (or if you have an Xbox music subscription, it will actually play the whole thing but will have a streaming icon next to it).

Try this to permanatly remove it:

1. Open Music app
2. Slide over to "Collection"
3. Select "Songs"
4. Now tap the green "showing" filter option above the song list, a "Filter by:" selection list will pop up.
5. Select "Streaming" (Now, you should see a list of all songs not on your device but still can be played)
6. Tap and hold the old song for the context menu
7. Select "Delete".

It will warn you if you want to permanently remove it from your cloud collection. Select yes and it should be removed.